# reformat excel text column to specific format

Tags: excel

I have a column in my excel that includes authors name and it looks as follows:

[image]

My goal is to remove the dates + the last comma from all of these rows to make it something like this:

[image]

Is there a way I can do it in excel?

Comment: Yes, using VBA you can do that.

Comment: You should be able to so that with formulas:  Check if the last substring is numeric; if it is remove it and the preceding comma; if not, leave it alone.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, in which there are multiple commas in one cell, I would go with determining the position of the last comma first (in order to know where to slice the content of said cell). Then it's a matter of `IF` formula based on condition in which the last 4 characters in the cell are digits:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,4))),LEFT(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))))-1),A1)`

FYI: The "@" substitution is targeted at knowing exactly where the last comma occurs in the cell. Any other unique, not-appearing-in-the-string character would have done the same job.

I've tested the formula on below examples:

[image]